# Subscription auto canceled after payment paypal

Tags: paypal, subscription, unsubscribe

this is my code (form subscription):

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="enrique.sevilla.11@gmail.com ">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<? echo $user; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="ES">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Pago mensual Monetiza.me">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="39">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="Servicios">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo $urlPredeterminada; ?>pago/ok">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo $urlPredeterminada; ?>pago/ko">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="image_url" value="http://www.monetiza.me/images/logo-monetiza.png">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo $urlPredeterminada; ?>ipn.php">
<input type="hidden" name="suscripcion" value="si">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="39">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
```

This form records the payment and subscription, but after a few minutes the subscription is canceled and get an email confirming that has been canceled. How do I prevent self unsubscribe?

Sorry for my English, i am a peruvian developer :(

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. I am not sure your html has something to do with the problem, maybe you can try to give a better description?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `src=1` to indicate that the payments will recur on a monthly basis:

```
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
```